# Getting "Must enable billing on Google Cloud Project"

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am sending an address to the Maps API, need the Lat & Lon of the address.

I pass in the request https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=.....

and the error message is what you see in the subject.

I am in the Cl

Comment: Well, do you have billing enabled on GCP?

Comment: You know the solution which is to enable billing for your project. What is the problem?

Comment: Pay for what you want to use, this is what it says. And now what is the business related question?

Answer (score 2):

Some Google Cloud Services are free and you can use it right away, but some others require to have an associated billing account although they are free, just in case you exceed the free usage allowed.

You have to enable billing account on the Google Cloud Project.

If you don't have one, first create a billing account:

https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account

Then, associate the project to the billing account:

https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project